# Sqlite syntax error code 1 in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanna create a simple db but i got syntax error can anyone help me to fix this.Here is my db helper:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="userDatabase";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="person";
private static final String USER_NAME="user";

public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_USER_TABLE="create table"+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +USER_NAME+"text primary key);";
    arg0.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

}
```

I got this error:
02-12 13:41:26.527: E/AndroidRuntime(6773): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableperson": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tableperson(usertext primary key);

Comment: ok i will do this for you: *02-12 13:41:26.527: E/AndroidRuntime(6773): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableperson": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: **create tableperson(usertext primary key);*** ... you see, no? ok: *create **tableperson** (usertext primary key);*

Comment: Chnage statemanet like this **String CREATE_USER_TABLE="create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +USER_NAME+" text primary key);";**

Comment: off-topic as: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error.***  ... now i'm waiting for reputation's miners answers ...

Comment: there should be a space between "table" and "tablename" , just google  Sqlite...you need to read more

Comment: Also a space is missing before the column data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot some whitespaces in the string

```
String CREATE_USER_TABLE="create table "+TABLE_NAME+" ("
        +USER_NAME+" text primary key);";
arg0.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing space on the right of *create table*

```
String CREATE_USER_TABLE="create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +USER_NAME+"text primary key);";
```

Comment: And also before the column data type.

Answer (score -1):

//sample code

//Declare db name,version

```
private static final String DB_NAME="babysteps.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION =1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Baby_Master";
```

//coloumn//(Table Baby_Master)

```
public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME="Name";
public static final String KEY_DOB="DOB";
public static final String KEY_GENDER="Gender";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL ="Email_id";
public static final String KEY_IMAGENAME ="Image_Name";
public static final String KEY_PEDNAME="Ped_Name";
public static final String KEY_PEDPHONE="Ped_phone";
public static final String KEY_PEDLOCATION="Location";
public static final String KEY_PEDEMAIL="Ped_Email";
public static final String KEY_CLOUDID="Cloud_Bid";
```

//Sample code to create table

```
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
        KEY_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_IMAGENAME + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_PEDNAME + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_PEDPHONE + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_PEDLOCATION + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_PEDEMAIL + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_CLOUDID + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
);
```